# What is the purpose of each of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations attributes?

Tags: .net, entity, data-annotations

I am making an MVC 3 application using entity framework 4 with POCOs. I want to annotate all my entitys as much as possible. I am having a problem however that I cannot find good documentation on the meaning of every attribute. Some are pretty straight forward, like `[Required]` or `[StringLength(...)]`. With attributes like `[Association]` however, I am not 100% sure. Do I put it on a navigation property? On a foreign key property? Only on many to many relations? Is `thisKey` the primary key of this object or the foreign key in this object?

I cannot find any good resource which lists all these properties with a good explanation and examples.

For association, MSDN just says:"Specifies that an entity member represents a data relationship, such as a foreign key relationship."
and "thisKey: A comma-separated list of the property names of the key values on the thisKey side of the association."

I got an answer to a more specific question about one of the attributes:
Association: [How do I use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociationAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389603/how-do-i-use-system-componentmodel-dataannotations-associationattribute)

Comment: You can refer this link. You will get idea.... [http://www.dotnetattributes.com/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations](http://www.dotnetattributes.com/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations)

Comment: Uhm... did you even look at that link yourself? It's even less informative than MSDN.

Comment: Doesn't matter how much amount of information is given. The thing how easily we can derive from that.

Comment: @Yoko: It doesn't answer any of my questions. E.g. for association it says "Represents an attribute that is used to specify that an entity property participates in an association.". What do they mean with "participate"?

Comment: Its right. I think you misunderstood that.....

Comment: It's right? The information is correct, but not specific enough. I still don't know how to use the association attribute. As I said in the question:"Do I put it on a navigation property? On a foreign key property? Only on many to many relations? Is thisKey the primary key of this object or the foreign key _in_ this object?". Can you answer those questions based on the information provided by that link?

Comment: Ok Fine. I am still finding on that. And will give you when i will have.

Answer (score 1):

The AssociationAttribute does nothing for entity framework code-first on a navigation property. It may seem like it does, but it's really just EF's convention-based logic for creating the db.