# How do I use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociationAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, poco, data-annotations

Some time ago I asked this question: [What is the purpose of each of the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076027/what-is-the-purpose-of-each-of-the-system-componentmodel-dataannotations-attribut)

However, I had no luck with getting replies. This question was a bit broad in the sense that it asked for documentation about every dataannotation attribute. At this moment, I am mostly interested in the `Association` attribute.

I am using ASP.NET MVC3 with Entity Framework 4 and would like to annotate my POCOs. I am using foreign keys in my POCOs (somehow feels wrong, but it seems to be generally accepeted). How do I annotate my POCO with the `Association` attribute? On which properties do I put it (`Association` property and/or foreign key property)? What are the `thisKey` and `otherKey` parameters. Is `thisKey` this POCOs key, or the foreign key in this POCO?

Then lastly, what will use this attribute? Is there something in ASP.NET MVC?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AssociationAttribute (in conjuction with the ExternalReferenceAttribute) is used by WCF RIA Services in Silverlight. With this attribute the client can resolve associations between entities from diffrent Domains.

I think it is specific to RIA Services. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422034%28v=VS.91%29.aspx)´s a walkthrough how it gets applied in WCF RIA Services.

A simple Example looks like

```
public class Customer{
   public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Order{

  public int Id {get;set;}

  public int CustomerId {get;set;}  //ForeignKey of the Customer

  [ExternalReference]
  [Association("Customer", "CustomerId", "Id")]
  public Customer {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Be aware that not all attributes provided in `DataAnnotations` namespace are related to Entity framework. I thought that `AssociationAttribute` is used in Linq-to-sql but it is actually different class with the same name from System.Data.Linq assembly. I just checked usage of `AssociationAttribute` by Reflector and it looks like neither Entity Framework (including code first), ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Dynamic data or WPF use it.

Comment: You're absolutely right.. AssociationAttribute does nothing for EF.